# Azure Cloud Services and Web Jobs

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure cloud service in which there are multiple background processing tasks which I would like to turn into WebJobs. I've read all I could find on the subject but it seems that WebJobs are tightly related to Web Apps and not Cloud services. I managed to create a web job in my cloud service solution and it seems it deployed correctly but I can't find a way to see it or its output on the new Azure portal (I couldn't see it in the classic management portal either)

Can one have a set of WebJobs running with a cloud service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Jobs is a feature specific to Azure Web Apps. You'd need to create a Web App (in an App Service Plan) to create your Web Jobs. These are unrelated to Cloud Services (web/worker roles).

Comment: Thank you. My issue is that I have some processing tasks I would like the webjob to take care of which require the presence of client certificates on the VM and this is not achievable with a web app :(

Comment: Just remember that you can trigger code in your web / worker role instances, via a web job (as long as you have a way to reach the web/worker code, via API call, queue message, etc). This might be of assistance to you, since Web Jobs have scheduling functionality not found in cloud services.

Comment: Thanks a lot David. We've actually considered that but are hesitating to go down that path since there will still be a considerable load on our main web role