# Can you run a scheduled Azure WebJob anywhere other than Azure?

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have an Azure scheduled WebJob that is running as expected (on a cron based schedule)

Now, if I wanted to, how could I run this (schedule and all) on a VM, or on another cloud provider?

Or am I locked into the Azure vendor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Cloud Services and Web Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048982/azure-cloud-services-and-web-jobs)

Comment: Not really, I can't find any documentation that explicitly states whether these IHostedServices/BackgroundService implementations are basically vendor lock-ins

Answer (score 0):

In Azure:  **Functions**  are used to scheduled jobs using Timer Trigger, i.e., similar to the  ***Scheduled Web Jobs***.

> Or am I locked into the Azure vendor?

You can achieve the same use case of Scheduled Web Jobs in  **AWS**  using  **Lambda Functions**  with the help of  ***CloudWatch***  Events.

It means you can configure that the CloudWatch Event to trigger the Lambda function defined by you at every X amount of time in which X is the CRON expression.

Comment: Is there a way for me to deploy my software which implements BackgroundService as a Lambda Function like I do from Visual Studio? (e.g. Publish profiles publishes directly to an Azure App Service and it just works)